# ¿Porque Android studio no me reconoce la librería de JBCD?

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo el siguiente código para generar una conexión a base de datos, el problema es que me aparece error a pesar de que ya importe la libreria y lo hice de dos formas, poniéndola en la carpeta libs y poniendo "Archivo/ Nuevo/ Nuevo módulo/Importar .Jar .aar package" y de ninguna forma me la reconoce. ¿Que error estoy cometiendo?

```
public Connection conexionDB () {
        Connection cnn = null;
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy politica = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(politica);

            Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver").newInstance();
            cnn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://server:port/DBNAME", "USER", "PASS");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return cnn;

    }
    public void consultarUser () {
        try {
            Statement stm = conexionDB().createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT user FROM usuarios WHERE id=1");
            if (rs.next()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rs.getString(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Android usa generalmente SQLite si se trata de tener una BD local en el dispositivo, y el manejo, conexión, consulta de datos es totalmente otro. Actualmente se usa Room que es parte de lo que se conoce como *Componentes de Arquitectura*, significa que **JDBC no tiene ningún sentido en Android**. Y si es una base de datos remota entonces tendrías que programar una API y mandar peticiones a dicha API con Volley, Retrofit, AsyncTask u otro.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas cargar un .jar en tu proyecto Android debes copiar el `.jar` dentro del directorio `/libs`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y dentro de tu archivo `build.gradle` en el bloque `dependencies`, definir la implementación des las clases del .jar:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...

    implementation files('libs/Archivo.jar')

    ...
    ...

}
```